# Collect global top-k from each node's list in MPI

Tags: parallel-processing, mapreduce, mpi, distributed-computing, distributed-system

I am running MPI instances in parallel. At some point, every instance has a list of 100 ranked values. I now want to collect the top-100 values from all the instances.

How can this be done in MPI? Is there a specialized function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

if you want to collect the top value of each instance, then `MPI_Gather()` is the right choice.

if you want to collect the 100 top values of all instances (e.g. the 100 top values amont n*100 values), then i do not think there is a "native" way to achieve that.
/* when you write `list`, i hope you really meant `array` */

that being said, you can use `MPI_Op_create()` in order to create an operator that works on two arrays, and then invoke `MPI_Reduce()` with the previously defined operator.

Comment: Yes, I want to collect the 100 top values of all instances, and yes they are arrays. I just wanted to imply they are sorted already. I will look into op_create, thanks. Shame there is no more direct way...

Answer (score 2):

Gilles's suggestion is a very elegant one so I thought I'd write a simple example code as this would make an excellent exercise in user-defined operations for those learning MPI.

Note that I have abused the meaning of the "len" argument to the user-defined operation. This is meant to be the number of reductions to be performed and *not* the size of each reduction. In other words, len=5 should mean that you want to sort 5 independent lists on each process, and not that each process has a single list of length 5. To fix this would require defining a new MPI datatype appropriate for a complete list (e.g. MPI_Type_contiguous) but I can't get that working right now.

However, even this technically incorrect code illustrates the basic approach.

The sample output for lists of length 5 on 3 processes is:

```
rank 0, mysortedlist[0] = 12
rank 0, mysortedlist[1] = 9
rank 0, mysortedlist[2] = 6
rank 0, mysortedlist[3] = 3
rank 0, mysortedlist[4] = 0

rank 2, mysortedlist[0] = 14
rank 2, mysortedlist[1] = 11
rank 2, mysortedlist[2] = 8
rank 2, mysortedlist[3] = 5
rank 2, mysortedlist[4] = 2

rank 1, mysortedlist[0] = 13
rank 1, mysortedlist[1] = 10
rank 1, mysortedlist[2] = 7
rank 1, mysortedlist[3] = 4
rank 1, mysortedlist[4] = 1

rank 0, sortedlist[0] = 14
rank 0, sortedlist[1] = 13
rank 0, sortedlist[2] = 12
rank 0, sortedlist[3] = 11
rank 0, sortedlist[4] = 10
```

Here's the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <mpi.h>

#define N 5

void mergesortint(void *vinvec, void *vinoutvec, int *n, MPI_Datatype *type);
void mergelist(int *merge, int *a, int *b, int n);

int main(void)
{
  int i;

  // local sorted list

  int mysortedlist[N];

  // global sorted list

  int sortedlist[N];

  MPI_Comm comm;

  MPI_Op MPI_MERGESORT;

  //  int rank, size;

  int size, rank;

  comm = MPI_COMM_WORLD;

  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

  MPI_Comm_size(comm, &size);
  MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &rank);

  // Register new reduction operation

  MPI_Op_create(mergesortint, 1, &MPI_MERGESORT);

  // Generate sorted lists on each rank

  for (i=0; i < N; i++)
    {
      mysortedlist[i] = rank+size*(N-i-1);
      sortedlist[i]   = -1;
    }

  for (i=0; i < N; i++)
   {
      printf("rank %d, mysortedlist[%d] = %d\n", rank, i, mysortedlist[i]);
    }
  printf("\n");

  // Perform reduction to rank 0

  MPI_Reduce(mysortedlist, sortedlist, N, MPI_INT, MPI_MERGESORT, 0, comm);

  if (rank == 0)
    {
      for (i=0; i < N; i++)
        {
          printf("rank %d, sortedlist[%d] = %d\n", rank, i, sortedlist[i]);
        }
      printf("\n");
    }

  MPI_Finalize();

  return 0;
}


void mergesortint(void *vinvec, void *vinoutvec, int *n, MPI_Datatype *type)
{
  int i;
  int nvec = *n;

  int *invec    = (int *) vinvec;
  int *inoutvec = (int *) vinoutvec;
  int *mergevec = (int *) malloc(nvec*sizeof(int));

  mergelist(mergevec, invec, inoutvec, nvec);

  for (i=0; i < nvec; i++)
    {
      inoutvec[i] = mergevec[i];
    }

  free(mergevec);
}


void mergelist(int *merge, int *a, int *b, int n)
{
  int i, ia, ib;

  ia = 0;
  ib = 0;

  for (i=0; i < n; i++)
    {
      if (a[ia] > b[ib])
        {
          merge[i] = a[ia];
          ia++;
        }
      else
        {
          merge[i] = b[ib];
          ib++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the full code that works for multiple lists, i.e. the "count" argument to MPI_Reduce() is correctly interpreted as the number of individual lists and not the length of each list. Although the list length N is a constant in main, the reduction operation is more general and computes the length from the list type extent.

Here's the output for 3 lists of length 5 on 4 processes:

```
dsh@laptop> mpirun -n 4 ./mergesortlist

rank 1, mysortedlist[0] =  17 117 217
rank 1, mysortedlist[1] =  13 113 213
rank 1, mysortedlist[2] =   9 109 209
rank 1, mysortedlist[3] =   5 105 205
rank 1, mysortedlist[4] =   1 101 201

rank 2, mysortedlist[0] =  18 118 218
rank 2, mysortedlist[1] =  14 114 214
rank 2, mysortedlist[2] =  10 110 210
rank 2, mysortedlist[3] =   6 106 206
rank 2, mysortedlist[4] =   2 102 202

rank 3, mysortedlist[0] =  19 119 219
rank 3, mysortedlist[1] =  15 115 215
rank 3, mysortedlist[2] =  11 111 211
rank 3, mysortedlist[3] =   7 107 207
rank 3, mysortedlist[4] =   3 103 203

rank 0, mysortedlist[0] =  16 116 216
rank 0, mysortedlist[1] =  12 112 212
rank 0, mysortedlist[2] =   8 108 208
rank 0, mysortedlist[3] =   4 104 204
rank 0, mysortedlist[4] =   0 100 200

rank 0, sortedlist[0] =  19 119 219
rank 0, sortedlist[1] =  18 118 218
rank 0, sortedlist[2] =  17 117 217
rank 0, sortedlist[3] =  16 116 216
rank 0, sortedlist[4] =  15 115 215
```

and here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <mpi.h>

#define NUMLIST 3 // Number of distinct lists (of integers)
#define N 5       // Length of each list

void mergesortlist(void *vinvec, void *vinoutvec, int *n, MPI_Datatype *type);
void mergelist(int *merge, int *a, int *b, int n);

int main(void)
{
  int i, ilist;

  // local sorted list

  int mysortedlist[NUMLIST][N];

  // global sorted list

  int sortedlist[NUMLIST][N];

  MPI_Comm comm;

  MPI_Datatype MPI_LIST;
  MPI_Op MPI_MERGELIST;

  int size, rank;

  comm = MPI_COMM_WORLD;

  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

  MPI_Comm_size(comm, &size);
  MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &rank);

  // Define datatype appropriate for a single array of N integers

  MPI_Type_contiguous(N, MPI_INT, &MPI_LIST);
  MPI_Type_commit(&MPI_LIST);

  // Register new reduction operation to merge two sorted lists

  MPI_Op_create(mergesortlist, 1, &MPI_MERGELIST);

  // Generate sorted lists on each rank

  for (i=0; i < N; i++)
    {
      for (ilist=0; ilist < NUMLIST; ilist++)
      {
        mysortedlist[ilist][i] = rank+size*(N-i-1) + 100*ilist;
        sortedlist[ilist][i] = -1;
      }
    }

  for (i=0; i < N; i++)
   {
     printf("rank %d, mysortedlist[%d] =", rank, i);

     for (ilist=0; ilist < NUMLIST; ilist++)
       {
         printf(" %3d", mysortedlist[ilist][i]);
       }
     printf("\n");
    }

  printf("\n");

  // Perform reduction to rank 0

  MPI_Reduce(mysortedlist, sortedlist, NUMLIST, MPI_LIST, MPI_MERGELIST,
         0, comm);

  if (rank == 0)
    {
      for (i=0; i < N; i++)
      {
        printf("rank %d, sortedlist[%d] =", rank, i);

        for (ilist=0; ilist < NUMLIST; ilist++)
        {
          printf(" %3d", sortedlist[ilist][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
      }

      printf("\n");
    }

  MPI_Finalize();

  return 0;
}


void mergesortlist(void *vinvec, void *vinoutvec, int *n, MPI_Datatype *type)
{
  MPI_Aint lb, listextent, intextent;

  int i, ilist;
  int nvec, nlist;

  int *invec    = (int *) vinvec;
  int *inoutvec = (int *) vinoutvec;

  // the count is the number of individual lists

  nlist = *n;

  // Infer length of each list from the extents
  // Should really check "type" is valid, i.e. a contiguous block of ints

  MPI_Type_get_extent(MPI_INT, &lb, &intextent);
  MPI_Type_get_extent(*type, &lb, &listextent);

  nvec = listextent/intextent;

  // Need a temporary as "mergelist" does not work in-place

  int *mergevec = (int *) malloc(nvec*sizeof(int));

  // Merge each of the "nlist" lists in turn

  for (ilist=0; ilist < nlist; ilist++)
    {
      mergelist(mergevec, &invec[ilist*nvec], &inoutvec[ilist*nvec], nvec);

      for (i=0; i < nvec; i++)
      {
        inoutvec[ilist*nvec+i] = mergevec[i];
      }
    }

  free(mergevec);
}


void mergelist(int *merge, int *a, int *b, int n)
{
  int i, ia, ib;

  ia = 0;
  ib = 0;

  for (i=0; i < n; i++)
    {
      if (a[ia] > b[ib])
        {
          merge[i] = a[ia];
          ia++;
        }
      else
        {
          merge[i] = b[ib];
          ib++;
        }
    }
}
```